# How can i play a video on device from server?

Tags: ios

I am trying to play a video that is on my server. its short video. Nearly 2 minutes. i must download it and play whenever download finished. How can i do that. i havent opinion? do you know any article or code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);  
    [moviePlayer play];`enter code here`
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But where do you  define moviePlayer ?Which framework shall i add?

Comment: Add MediaPlayer.framework in frameworks and write .h file  <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> and check in device..